# Writing axes titles with units raised to negative powers in matplotlib with TeX and matching formatting

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I'm writing a lab report for uni and have decided to use pyplot to draw a graph for it. The units for one of my axes is V^(-1), but I can't seem to get matplotlib to write that with the power in superscript (it only superscripts the minus sign) when using the code:

```
    plt.xlabel('$1/U (10^5 V ^-1 )$')
```

I'd also like to match the fonts used for the axes titles with that used for the values on the axes if at all possible. I've tried putting:

```
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('font', family='serif')
```

at the beginning of my code, but that gives me the error:

`File "C:\Users\Sam\Documents\Uni\Labs\pytry.py", line 92, in <module>
    plt.savefig("Xrayplot.png")
      File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 561, in savefig
    return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1421, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_wxagg.py", line 85, in print_figure
    FigureCanvasAgg.print_figure(self, filename, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2220, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 505, in print_png
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 451, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1034, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 2086, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1089, in draw
    renderer)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1038, in _get_tick_bboxes
    extent = tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 753, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 320, in _get_layout
    ismath=False)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 205, in get_text_width_height_descent
    renderer=self)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 666, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
  File "C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\texmanager.py", line 413, in make_dvi
    'LaTeX: \n\n' % repr(tex)) + report)
RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
'lp'
Here is the full report generated by LaTeX:`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the superscript add { } around the text that should be super scripted. For the fonts i don't know the solution.

```
 plt.xlabel('$1/U (10^5 V ^{-1} )$')
```